# Hide tooltip with jquery issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I know there are a few questions related to this issue however I don’t seem to be able to find a solution for my case. I would like to hide the native tooltip action when a user hovers over an anchor tag with a title attribute. I don't want to remove the title, as it is used by Fancybox, I just want to remove the default tooltip action.

This is the script I’m trying to use, however when I substitute the ‘suppress’ classname it doesn’t work:

```
// Suppress tooltip display for links that have the classname 'suppress'
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
if (links[i].className == 'suppress') {
    links[i]._title = links[i].title;
    links[i].onmouseover = function() { 
        this.title = '';
    }
    links[i].onmouseout = function() { 
        this.title = this._title;
    }
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<li class="item-thumbs span3 photography">
<a class="hover-wrap fancybox1" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="_include/img/work/full/image-04-full.jpg" title="text about the project :: <a href='http://www.someclient.com'>Launch website</a>">
<span class="overlay-img"></span>
<span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-search"></span>
                            </a>
```

Apologies for this dupe question, I just can find a solution amongst all the suggestions that work for my specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use the (HTML5) `data-fancybox-title` attribute (fancybox v2.x). It doesn't show on hover but still it's used by fancybox .... and not need of using callbacks so

this html

```
<a data-fancybox-title="Lorem ipsum" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

and this script

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

... will work just fine; see **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PebW3/)**

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there any reason you may recommend using one option over the other? Just curious.

Comment: @user2247476 : I would use callbacks only when is strictly necessary. `data-fancybox-title` is already integrated in the code so no need to perform extra functions.

Answer (score 1):

If use fancybox2:

```
$(".fancybox")
.fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
    }
});
```

see exsample http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/